# org-mode spreadsheet multiply 2 columns element-wise using GNU Emacs Calc formula

Tags: org-mode, calc, spreadsheet

I am looking for a way to multiply 2 columns element by element and then sum the resulting vector. I have the following example:

```
|   |       | col1 | enable |
|---+-------+------+--------|
|   |       |    1 |      1 |
|   |       |    3 |      0 |
|   |       |      |      0 |
|   |       |    7 |      1 |
|---+-------+------+--------|
| # | sum   |   11 |      2 |
| # | value |      |        |
#+TBLFM: @6$3=vsum(@I$3..@II$3);N::@6$4=vsum(@I$4..@II$4);N
```

Now I want to add up all values of column `col1`, where there is a `1` in the `enable` column. The `enable` column determins, whether the value in column `col1` is mathematically considered, because multiplied by `0`, it will become an addend of `0` in the sum.

Mathematically speaking I want to:

```
result = sum_{i=0}^i=2 (col1_i * enable_i)
```

How can I achieve this?

I found `inner` on https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Generalized-Products.html#Generalized-Products and https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Function-Index.html#Function-Index, but do no understand how to make use of it or whether it is what I am looking for (not so firm in the terminology).

If the answer is, that this is not possible with a GNU Emacs Calc formula, that's also fine and good to know, but I think it should be possible, as it seems rather basic.

I would like to avoid having to add an extra column for the products and then summing that. The more clutter I can avoid, the better, as this table might get much wider in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess `inner` is right. The first two operands of `inner` are the multiplication and the summation operator, respectively. The remaining two arguments are the vectors for the inner product.

The summation operator is `add` and the multiplication operator is `mul`.

Your table inclusive the table-formula should look like:

```
|   |       | col1 | enable |
|---+-------+------+--------|
|   |       |    1 |      1 |
|   |       |    3 |      0 |
|   |       |    0 |      0 |
|   |       |    7 |      1 |
|---+-------+------+--------|
| # | value |    8 |        |
#+TBLFM: @>$3=inner(mul,add,@I$3..@II$3,@I$4..@II$4)
```

Comment: Wow, if I understand this correctly, it means, that I could use arbitrary other operations with `inner`. That makes it quite powerful.

Comment: Calc `*` calculates the inner product of two vectors, so for this particular case you really don't need `inner`: `#+TBLFM: @>$3=@I$3..@II$3 * @I$4..@II$4` will do, although the empty cell at `@4$3` does have to be filled in, as @Tobias has done in the answer: you cannot leave it empty or else the vectors have different dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward: use the EN options, as follows:

```
@7$3=vsum(@I..@II*@I$+1..@II$+1);EN
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the `orgtb-aggregate` package available on Melpa. It will create new tables from yours. In this example, partial sums are computed for similar values of `enable`:

```
#+name: mytable
|   |       | col1 | enable |
|---+-------+------+--------|
|   |       |    1 |      1 |
|   |       |    3 |      0 |
|   |       |      |      0 |
|   |       |    7 |      1 |

#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "mytable" :cols "enable vsum(col1)"
| enable | vsum(col1) |
|--------+------------|
|      1 |          8 |
|      0 |          3 |
#+END:
```

Alternately, you may apply the mathematical formula you gave:

```
#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "mytable" :cols "vsum(col1*enable);NE"
| vsum(col1*enable);NE |
|----------------------|
|                    8 |
#+END:
```

(The `;NE` format is useful to cope with an empty cell in the 3rd row)

https://github.com/tbanel/orgaggregate/blob/master/README.org

Answer (score 0):

You can create an auxiliary column to store the multiples:

```
|   |     | col1 | enable | mul |
|---+-----+------+--------+-----|
|   |     |    1 |      1 |   1 |
|   |     |    3 |      0 |   0 |
|   |     |      |      0 |   0 |
|   |     |    7 |      1 |   8 |
|---+-----+------+--------+-----|
| # | sum |   11 |      2 |   9 |
#+TBLFM: $5=$3*$4::@6$3=vsum(@I$3..@II$3);N::@6$4=vsum(@I$4..@II$4);N::@6$5=vsum(@I..@II)
```

Comment: Yes, that is one way, however, I would like to avoid an unnecessary column for this (see question / OP).