# Calculating weighted average in orgmode table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In the following table

```
| Item   | Weight | Grade |
|--------+--------+-------|
| Quizes |    .15 |     3 |
| Exam 1 |     .3 |     5 |
| Exam 2 |     .5 |     4 |
|--------+--------+-------|
| Total  |        |       |
```

What formula can I use to calculate a weighted average (.15*3+.3*5+.5*4) and print it in `@5$3`?

The best I have so far is `#+TBLFM: @5$3=@2$3*@2$2+@3$2*@3$3+@4$2*@4$3`, but there has to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: This just requires an inner product of two vectors. See [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57978/org-mode-spreadsheet-multiply-2-columns-element-wise-using-gnu-emacs-calc-formul/57981#57981).

Comment: @NickD that one works. Thanks